# JPA NamedQuery with Object in WHERE clause that is converted using AttributeConverter

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have got a bit of a problem using JPA NamedQuery in combination with an AttributeConverter.

So basically, I have got an Entity with a field xyz of type XYZ, that is converted using `AttributeConverter<XYZ, String>`, so the value is stored as a VARCHAR in the database. This works nicely. But I'm not quite sure about how to query for Entity.xyz using a NamedQuery:

`@NamedQuery(name="Entity.testQuery", query="SELECT e FROM Entity e WHERE e.xyz=:xyz`

If I try it in this way, Hibernate crashes during startup. So that can't be right. Is there any way to tell Hibernate to compare the "unconverted" (i.e. String) value like `WHERE e.xyz=:xyzAsString`?

Best regards
Jonas

EDIT: Hibernate crashes, I think, because it tries to query e.xyz as a JOIN with entity XYZ which doesn't exist. So maybe, this is a bug (I'm on WildFly 9.2, which uses Hibernate 4.3)

Comment: Why would it crash? Show the exception and messages you get, as it seems strange not to tell you something. The query contains a parameter, so it should only need a type when the query gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter has to be of type XYZ and not String. Use converter method to obtain corresponding instance XYZ for needed String value.

Comment: Hibernate crashes during deployment, even before I can try to execute the query with a given parameter. I think, all the named queries are parsed during startup

Answer (score 0):

After adding some changes in other places, the problem no longer occurs. So my conclusion, that it is related to a converted attribute as parameter seems to be wrong.

Thanks nonetheless